# GeoExt AttributeStore not loading data

Tags: extjs, openlayers, geoext

I am having problems loading data into an attribute store using a WFS request.

I am using the code below to create the store.

```
var attrStore = new GeoExt.data.AttributeStore({
                url: "http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/ows",
                baseParams: {
                                SERVICE: "WFS",
                                REQUEST: "DescribeFeatureType",
                                VERSION: "1.1.0",
                                TYPENAME: layerID
                },
                autoLoad: true
})
```

I have tried adding listeners to see what is happening, the beforeload listener fires but not the load and the WFS request is not being sent. There are no errors in Firebug.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to use AttributeStore? If for edit feature's attributes that better to use FeatureStore+ExtJs.GridPanelEditor.
AnyWey there is example what you want. http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/attributes.html